# Use a `title` variable from certain place into a much higher template

Tags: angular

I have a template which works nice (so far) for my application. There is a sidebar, a header and a footer, each of them in its own component and all the building blocks are in place.

The issue is, I want to use a certain information referred to the view being used --e.g. the enquiries module has a enquiry-new component and I want to show "New Enquiry" as a title in the header component.

I started using a service, but I am not sure on how to update it, given that I tried that but had the mistake of using the `ngOnInit` (which is called once, so there is no refresh/tracking on the title).

I tried to pass around arbitrary data into the routes, with the `data` variable. The problem I found is that the `ActivatedRoute`'s `data` observable gives the data for the parent, not childs. I could use `firstChild`, but then the title does not refresh when the route changes.

I was looking into documentation on using an `Input` approach, but as the templates are using `router-outlet` it doesn't seem to work (I have not been able to make Angular like it, and still, I don't know how to refresh it properly).

Is there a proper way to do this? Am I having any sensible approach? Maybe I am focusing from a bad point of view, but I don't see how to do it in a simple fashion.

---

I felt that posting code would be confusing, but maybe it gives some ideas to what I want / what I tried. Maybe the following code is complete garbage and I have been in a wrong track. Maybe it can be salvaged. Note that using a service or using the route's data are different (exclusive?) approaches, and I got stuck with both.

```js
// header.component.ts

@Component({
(...)
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  ngOnInit() {
    // Conceptually, using Tried using a service here
    this.title = this.extraRouteInfoService.getTitle();
    // alternatively, something along
    this.title = this.route.data.pipe(map(data => data.title));
    // or with some conceptual method that doesn't exist
    this.title = this.route.getDataForLastChildCurrentRoute(magic);
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- header.component.html -->
<div>
...
<h1>{{ title | async }}</h1>
...
</div>
```

```html
<!-- home.component.html -->
<div>
<app-layout-header></app-layout-header>
  <main class="content">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </main>
</div>
```

```js
// home-routing.module.ts
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    data: {
      title: 'Home',
    },
    children: [
      {
        path: 'enquiries',
        loadChildren: '../enquiries/enquiries.module#EnquiriesModule'
      }
    ]
  }
];
//(...)
```

```js
// enquiries-routing.module.ts

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: EnquiryListComponent,
    data: {
      title: 'All enquiries'
    }
  },
  {
    path: 'new',
    component: EnquiryNewComponent,
    data: {
      title: 'New enquiry'
    }
  }
];
//(...)
```

Comment: Please post some code.

Comment: @SachinGupta I hope it's not too confusing now. Given that I don't know if the approach I have makes sense at all, I wasn't sure if it showing that code would end up helping or distracting potential answers.

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service

Comment: @JBNizet I looked at that link. But the relationship between header (_what renders the title_) and the main component (_what gives specific title_) is not direct, given that there is a `home.module.ts` making the layout. And also, when I tried using the service just as in the documentation, I was stuck with routes not triggering updates to whatever because I am missing the correct machinery to make everything work. Am I missing something more obvious?

Comment: You're missing the fact that whether or not the relationship is direct or not doesn't matter at all. As long as the two components share a service instance, one component can emit events, though a Subject exposed by the service, and the other one can subscribe to vents being emitted.